# Tirar Relatório com meses zerado

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, query, select

Eu tenho uma query em que eu tiro mensalmente valores depositados ele pega tudo que tem na base e mostra os meses que foram inseridos na base.

Eu gostaria de fazer diferente gostaria que mostrasse também os meses que não tiveram deposito gostaria de trazer zerado conforme a imagem abaixo meu banco é o Postgres.

**Como Traz Hoje**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como Gostaria de Trazer**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Query**

```
SELECT to_char(fi.data,'yyyy/mm') as Mês, count(fi.*) as valor 
  FROM financeiro fi 
  WHERE fi.status = '1' 
  GROUP BY Mês 
  ORDER BY Mês;
```

Comment: Uma solução para Oracle , veja se ajuda http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/522521-forcar-select-trazer-linha-mesmo-que-sem-valor/

Comment: Tentei montar aqui mas nao deu certo

Comment: vai ser por ano, vai ter um filtro?

Comment: http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/278755-numero-da-linha-no-mysql-tipo-rownum-no-oracle/

Comment: Por meses @VirgilioNovic

Comment: mas, por exemplo você escolhe o ano ou isso para você é indeferente?

Comment: Por enquanto é indiferente

Comment: É MySQL ou postgresql? Convém especificar, a solução pode ser diferente em cada caso.

Comment: Eu especifiquei o Banco é Postgres

Answer (score 1):

Faça um `outer join` com `generate_series`:

```
select to_char(d.data,'yyyy/mm') as Mês, count(fi.*) as valor 
from
    financeiro fi
    right join
    generate_series(
        '2016-01-01'::date, '2016-12-01, '1 month'
    ) gs (d) on d = date_trunc('month', fi.data)
where fi.status = '1' 
group by mês 
order by mês;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para exibir também os valores NULL precisamos usar uma a função que substitui o valor null por um valor desejado, nesse caso o 0. Dependendo do banco que vc está usando a sintaxe muda mas no oracle é nvl([o seu campo],0)

Se seu banco for oracle tente chamar o campo valor assim:

```
nvl(fi.valor,0)
```

Comment: Obrigado @Guilherme não conhecia essa função vou tentar usar aqui e já te dou um retorno

Answer (score 0):

Você tambem sempre pode usar uma CTE e um CASE  (em postgres eu sempre prefiro utilizar CTE's para melhorar a leitura e dividir as querys

```
WITH consulta AS (
SELECT to_char(fi.data,'yyyy/mm') as Mes, count(fi.*) as valor 
FROM financeiro fi 
WHERE fi.status = '1' 
GROUP BY Mês 
ORDER BY Mês;
)
SELECT mes, 
CASE WHEN valor IS NULL THEN '0'
ELSE valor
END
FROM consulta
```